# Can't download Monodevelop any more - how do people make MVC apps on OSX now?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, monodevelop, xamarin

As the title states - when I go to dl MD I only get the option to dl Xamarin Studio.

I can't develop web apps in XS - so how is everyone doing their web stuff on mac now?

Answer (score 2):

You can develop web apps in XS just like you did with MD, since it is the same IDE.

Comment: Do I need to install two versions? My (paid for - so biz account) version of XS doesn't have the option to create a new web app?

Comment: The option is there, in the ASP.NET section of the New Project dialog.